# Need to display my one drive directories in to my web page using "Microsoft Graph"

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I need to display my one drive directories in to my web page using "Microsoft Graph" and organize them. Is it possible ? I already have created an angular app, Registered with Azure AD and also invoked microsoft graph api in to my webpage. I am able to get all the Outlook calendar data. Now I need all the OneDrive items to access them from my Webpage. Please do help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To access one drive items you simply run this request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```

It gives you a list of all items in your OneDrive. You can use the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) tool to help you see the response to expect so that you can iterate through it and display it on your webpage